# How to encode multiple String columns in the dataset while preprocessing?

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I am very new to Machine learning and as part of learning, I was going thru the data preprocessing.

This is how my dataset looks like:

[image]

I wanted to predict the delete_ind based on the data I have in first three columns.
These are the steps I followed.

```
schema = StructType([StructField('id', StringType(), True), \
                     StructField('company_code', StringType(), True), \
                     StructField("cost", FloatType(), True), \
                     StructField('delete_ind', StringType(), True)
                    ])

data = spark.sql('select id, company_code, cost, delete_ind from dbname.table limit 5000')
pdata = data.toPandas()
```

Selecting columns from Pandas Dataframe

```
x = pdata.iloc[:, 0:-1].values
y = pdata.iloc[:, -1].values
```

Adding default values in place of missing data

```
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
imputer.fit(x[:, 2:3])
```

Encoding the first two column of the dataset to default values

```
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [0:2])], remainder='passthrough')
x = np.array(ct.fit_transform(x))
```

While I am trying to encode the first two columns of `x`, I am seeing the below error.

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "<command-1856943148058177>", line 1
    ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [0:2])], remainder='passthrough')
                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could anyone let me know what is the mistake I am doing here ?

Comment: `[0:2]` isn't valid Python, error is saying that. That's the `columns` argument of [`ColumnTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html), and as stated in the documentation, it accepts a slice object so you can write `slice(2)` instead (among other options as the documentation states).

Comment: Understood. In case of using a Range, how can I implement it ? Because I want the first two columns. Does `slice(n)` work with just slicing first `n` columns or can I specify the columnar positions in it to pick up the columns I just want to encode ?

Comment: For the first two columns, `slice(2)` or, as the documentation says, `[0, 1]` or even, for readability maybe, `df.columns[:2]` might be used (last one possible if you keep the dataframe around). So for arbitrary selections, you can pass `[0, 7, 3]` to select those columns positionally. (Side note: `slice` is a Python object that goes behind the `1:9:2` syntax we use when indexing (`slice(1, 9, 2)`).) If you find me confusing, documentation is your friend :)